# Reuse artifacts at a later stage in the same Jenkins project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline whose Build step has an `archiveArtifacts` command.

After the Build step there is Unit test, Integration test and Deploy.

In Deploy step, I want to use one of the artifacts. I thought I could find it in the same place the Build step generated it, but apparently the `archiveArtifacts` has deleted them.

As a workaround I can copy the artifact before it is archived, but it doesn't look elegant to me. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As I understand it, archiveArtifacts is more for saving artifacts for use by something (or someone) after the build has finished. I would recommend looking at using "stash" and "unstash" for transferring files between stages or nodes.

You just go...

```
stash include: 'globdescribingfiles', name: 'stashnameusedlatertounstash'
```

and when you want to later retrieve that artifact...

```
unstash 'stashnameusedlatertounstash'
```

and the stashed files will be put into the current working directory.

Here's the example of that given in the Jenkinsfile docs (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-multiple-agents):

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh 'make'
                stash includes: '**/target/*.jar', name: 'app' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test on Linux') {
            agent { 
                label 'linux'
            }
            steps {
                unstash 'app' 
                sh 'make check'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit '**/target/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test on Windows') {
            agent {
                label 'windows'
            }
            steps {
                unstash 'app'
                bat 'make check' 
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit '**/target/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

Comment: This is apparently a bad idea for large files (i.e. if you're building / testing in multiple stages)

Comment: @SinaMadani what's your source for this info?

Comment: While stash works, indeed, it seems wasteful to have to use it when what you want has already been archived as an artifact.

Comment: @Brian Do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Crystal While I don't recall what my particular use-case/reason for wanting this functionality I would guess that my comment here was more directed at the Jenkins platform not making it easy to retrieve previously archived artifacts rather than having to duplicately store them as a stash.  That said, are the artifacts from a job in progress really not available with an HTTP client as they would be when the job finishes?

Comment: @Brian Different stages under the same job can be obtained through the form of a URL such as `http://xxx/job/test_pipeline/${env.BUILD_ID}/artifact/xxx/target/xxx-SNAPSHOT.jar`. But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way, haha.  Thanks for your reply.